# Android get different content in single activity

Tags: java, android

actually I'm searching a way to show different content in one activity everytime when it's created.Here is what actually I'm thinking to do but not really sure if there is a way and how can I do it. Basically I have two activities. The first one contains a listview with 100 elements on it.I want to be able to show different content in activity 2 when I click a listview item in Activity 1. I need to be able to change two textviews and one imageview.

Any suggestions how can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do somethins like this :

Activity 1:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("someKey","someValue");
startActivityForResult(Intent, 0);
```

Activity 2:

```
String i = getIntent().getStringExtra("someKey"));
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView); //your textview's id
txt.setText(i);
```

That should work!

Answer (score 2):

You want to use Intents to pass Payload between your Activitys.

On Activty1 you make a new Intent like:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
Activty2.class);
myIntent.putExtra("detailtext", ((TextView) view).getText());
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

the putExtra Method is for your Payload.

then in Activty2 you can extract the Intent with:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("detailtext"));
```

hope that helps